# Number of sides of a regular polygon using LCM.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, polygons

I think this may be true, it works for all I’ve checked, but I’m not sure why. I stumbled across it when thinking that there must be a relation between the LCM of the interior angle and 180 degrees.

To find the number of sides of a regular polygon with interior angle x.

Odd sided polygon:

LCM(x,180)/x

Even sided polygon;

2*LCM(x,180)/x

Any ideas why, and if it always works?

Comment: Have you tried any examples where the LCM is *not* equal to 180?  How do you define the LCM of... say... $\frac{40}{3}$ and $180$?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Realized after comment. Deleted.